# This command requires at least two rows of source data

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I am getting this error:

```
This command requires at least two rows of source data. You cannot use the command on a selection in only one row. Try the following:

- If you're using an advanced filter, select a range of cells that contains at least two rows of data. Then click the Advanced Filter command again.
- I you're creating a PivotTable, type a cell reference or select a range that includes at least two rows of data
```

intermittently on this line of code:

```
xlWorkBook.RefreshAll();
```

There are two worksheets. One has a pivot table and one has raw data. Sometimes there is only one row of data. For multiple rows of data the line of code above **always works**; however, for only 1 row of data, the code above **sometimes** works, and sometimes I get the error message above.

In addition to this, the worksheet containing the pivot table is **not** refreshed; however, if I re-open the file, it also **does not** refresh, unless I explicitly refresh it manually.

What is going on here? Why am I getting this error only *sometimes?*

Thank you so much for your guidance.

if at all helpful, i am including the entire method:

```
private void SortandCreateFile(string column, string email, string emailStartPos) {
    string replacetext = "";

    try {
        var valueRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(column + emailStartPos, column + range.Rows.Count.ToString());
        var deleteRange = valueRange;
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        int startpos = 0;
        int endPos=0;
        bool foundStart = false;

        Excel.Range rng = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(column + "1", column + range.Rows.Count.ToString());

        string tempstring = "d";
        int INTemailStartPos = Convert.ToInt16(emailStartPos);

        for (int rCnt = INTemailStartPos; rCnt <= rng.Count; rCnt++) {
            Excel.Range cell = (Excel.Range)rng[rCnt, 1];

            try {
                if (cell.Value2 != null)
                    tempstring = cell.Value2.ToString();
                else {
                    startpos = rCnt;
                    releaseObject(cell);  /////////
                    break;
                }
            }
                catch (Exception ee)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());
        }
        //grab the text from column link texdtbox
        Excel.Range rngLinkColumn;
        Excel.Range replacetextcell=null;

        if (FormControls.ColumnLink.Length > 0) {
            rngLinkColumn = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(FormControls.ColumnLink + "1", FormControls.ColumnLink + range.Rows.Count.ToString());
            replacetextcell = (Excel.Range)rngLinkColumn[rCnt, 1];
        }    
        //locate email
        if (cell.Value2.ToString() == email ) {
            //we found the starting position of the email we want!
            //this will tell us which row of data to start from
            startpos = rCnt;

            if (FormControls.ColumnLink.Length > 0)
                replacetext = replacetextcell.Value2.ToString();
            releaseObject(cell);  /////////
            break;
        }
        releaseObject(cell);
    }
    int foundstartminusONE = startpos - 1;
    int rngcount = rng.Count + INTemailStartPos;

    //delete everything from the top UNTIL the row of the email address that we need
    if (startpos != INTemailStartPos) {
        deleteRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(column + INTemailStartPos.ToString() + ":" + "CF" + foundstartminusONE.ToString(), Type.Missing);
        deleteRange = deleteRange.EntireRow;
        deleteRange.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
    }

    for (int rCnt = INTemailStartPos; rCnt <= rng.Count; rCnt++) {
        Excel.Range cell = (Excel.Range)rng[rCnt, 1];

        try {
            if (cell.Value2 != null )
                tempstring = cell.Value2.ToString();
            else {
                endPos = rCnt - 1;
                releaseObject(cell);////////
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee) {
            //MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());
        }    
        //locate email
        if (cell.Value2.ToString() != email ) {
            //we found where the last email address is that we need
            //this is where the issue is occurring i think with the deleting the last row
            endPos = rCnt;
            releaseObject(cell);////////
            break;
        }
        releaseObject(cell);
    }

    //delete all the stuff AFTER the email address that we need
    if (endPos != 0) {
        deleteRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(column + endPos + ":" + "CF" + rngcount.ToString(), Type.Missing);
        deleteRange = deleteRange.EntireRow;
        deleteRange.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
    }

    //when the user opens the excel file, we want the focus to be here
    var rangehome = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(FormControls.FocusOn, FormControls.FocusOn);
    xlWorkSheet.Activate();
    rangehome.Select();

    string filename = xlWorkBook.Path + @"\" + email + ".xlsx";
    string fileSubstring = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf(".xlsx"));
    string randomfileString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 10) + ".xlsx";
    string targetfilenameRename = fileSubstring + randomfileString;

    //((Excel.Worksheet)this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[FormControls.WorksheetFocus]).Activate();
    //((Excel.Worksheet)Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).Activate();  

    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetFocus = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(FormControls.WorksheetFocus);
    xlWorkSheetFocus.Activate();
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(targetfilenameRename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    try {
        xlWorkBook.RefreshAll();
    }
    catch { }
        xlWorkBook.Save();
        string targetfile = xlWorkBook.Path + @"\" + FormControls.FileName + " - "
                    + email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf("@")) + ".xlsx";
        System.IO.File.Copy(targetfilenameRename, targetfile, true);

        string body = FormControls.eMailBody;
        body = body.Replace("%replacetext%", replacetext);
        //replace %replacetext% in body
        string targetfileSubstring = targetfile.Substring(0, targetfile.IndexOf(".xlsx"));
        string randomString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 10)+".xlsx";
        string targetfileRename = targetfileSubstring+randomString;

        while (true) {
            try {
                SendEmail(targetfile, email, FormControls.eMailSubject, body,FormControls.eMailFrom);                                  
            }
            catch (Exception ee) {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());
                continue;
            }

            // all is good
            break;
        }
        releaseObject(valueRange);
        releaseObject(deleteRange);
        File.Copy(targetfile, targetfileRename, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
    finally {
        //DisposeMe();
        // Release all COM RCWs.
        // The "releaseObject" will just "do nothing" if null is passed,
        // so no need to check to find out which need to be released.
        // The "finally" is run in all cases, even if there was an exception
        // in the "try". 
        // Note: passing "by ref" so afterwords "xlWorkSheet" will
        // evaluate to null. See "releaseObject".
        releaseObject(range);
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        // The Quit is done in the finally because we always
        // want to quit. It is no different than releasing RCWs.
        if (xlApp != null) {
            xlApp.Quit();
        }
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }
}
```

Comment: when your data that is referenced by the pivot table is only one row, is it field names or still values?

Comment: try an `if` such as `if (rowcount > 1) { RefreshAll } else { RefreshActiveSheet }`

Comment: @BerkerYüceer thats an awesome idea!! can you please code it up into an answer?

Comment: you said you have pivot tables so solution is based on their attributes preparing an answer now.

Comment: @scott its both field names and valuers

Comment: You have field names and data values in the same row?

Comment: @scott nope, the field names are in their own separate row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I could replicate this error with a pivot table was by attempting to create one off a range that didn't have column headers, just like on the screenshot from Stephan1010's answer.

In the *GetPivotData* Excel function, pivot fields are referred to by their names (`=GETPIVOTDATA("EmailAddress",$A$3)`); thus, it makes sense to disallow a data source that wouldn't have them.

The solution would be to pivot over a `ListObject` instead of a `Range` - in Excel when you select, say, range `$A$1:$C$1` and *format as table* (from the Ribbon), the table that results will span `$A$1:$C$2`; the contents of the first row becomes the column headers and the second row is a valid, empty record. Interesting to note that this happens (the 2-row span) regardless of whether or not you check the "My table has headers" checkbox (the data will be moved to the first row and the table will contain default "Column1"-"Column2"-"Column3" headers if the checkbox is cleared).

In other words, a `ListObject` is *always* a valid data source for a pivot table, while a `Range` may not contain enough rows. Also if you don't have column headers and you create a pivot table with range `$A$1:$C$2`, the record at `$A$1:$C$1` will be used as column headers, which means that first record is lost.

From the code you have supplied I would presume the pivot table is already present and connected to some [named?] range in a template workbook that contains the macro. Turning your range into a table might be as trivial as selecting *format as table* from the Ribbon. And then you could have code like this to remove all unnecessary rows while still keeping a valid data source for the pivot table:

```
    public void DeleteExtraTableRows(string emailAddress, Excel.ListObject table)
    {
        try
        {
            var rowIndex = 0;
            var wasDeleted = false;
            while (rowIndex <= table.ListRows.Count)
            {
                if (!wasDeleted) rowIndex++;
                var row = table.ListRows[rowIndex];

                var range = (Excel.Range)row.Range.Cells[1, 1];
                var value = range.Value2;

                if (value != null && !string.Equals(emailAddress, value.ToString()))
                {
                    row.Delete();
                    wasDeleted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

There is also a possibility that the `email` is never found in the loop's `if (cell.Value2.ToString() == email )` condition, which would end up deleting all rows from your range - even if the only difference is an extra space at the end of the in-cell value. With the above code, even if all email addresses get deleted the data source remains a valid one for a pivot table that would be connected to it.

EDIT:
In Excel you turn a `Range` into a `ListObject` by selecting the range in question and clicking the *Format as table* Ribbon button, from the *Home* tab. Alternatively you can create one like this:

```
            var range = ((Excel.Range)(worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[1, 1], worksheet.Cells[3, 1]]));
            var table = worksheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType: Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, Source: range,
                                      XlListObjectHasHeaders: Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);
            table.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium3";
```

In code, you can access all `ListObjects` on a worksheet using the `ListObjects` property:

```
        var worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        var tables = worksheet.ListObjects;
```

Then, you can access a specific `ListObject` /table with several different ways:

```
        var myTable = tables[1];
        var myTable = tables.Item["Table1"];
        var myTable = tables.OfType<Excel.ListObject>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Table1");
```

As rows are added from the table, the actual range it refers to will be expanded accordingly; use `myTable.Range` to access the range in question.

Comment: i'm sorry i had initially thought that this did the trick, but it did not. having the same issue

Comment: No problem. Please update the question with your new updated code, connecting the pivot table to a `ListObject` instead of a `Range` has certainly made lots of range-handling code useless, and possibly changed the way you are accessing this data (like, `column+"1"` no more). I'm sure we can sort this out. Also there might be something I didn't fully understand in what you are trying to accomplish: My method deletes all rows from a table where the 1st column contains email addresses, except rows where the email address matches the specified string. Is this what you intended to be doing?

Comment: im sorry i dont understand how to select a listobject instead of a range, can you please explain?

Comment: thank you!! i also wanted to say that i dont think it's the tostring==email issue. i checked on this.

Comment: thanks so much! so after the last line in your code, i should run RefreshAll?

Comment: `RefreshAll()` will update all pivot tables. I would delete and then re-generate the pivot table (click anywhere in the table and then *insert*/*pivot table* from the Ribbon), just to make sure it refers to a valid data source. Calling `RefreshAll()` after that shouldn't give you any problems.

Comment: hello! i am getting many errors on this line: var table = worksheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType: Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, Source: range,
                                          XlListObjectHasHeaders: Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);

Comment: also for this:  var range = ((Excel.Range)(worksheet.Range did you mean  var range = ((Excel.Range)(worksheet.Cells ???

Comment: i've asked a question about your code here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12941399/117700

Answer (score 4):

i suppose this situation occurs because of the pivot tables you got.
cause refresh all will trigger pivot table's refresh command too.
look at the code below. It may give you an idea about it. Its not about 1 row im sure. i checked it everthing works just fine its most posibly caused by pivot tables.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("some.xlsx");
// For each worksheet we got
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet in xlWorkbook.Sheets) 
{   // and each pivot table in each worksheet
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable pivot in worksheet.PivotTables())
    {   // disable BackgroundQuery
        pivot.PivotTableWizard(BackgroundQuery: false);
    }
}
// try to refresh all sheet
try { xlWorkbook.RefreshAll(); } catch { }
// then save
xlWorkbook.Save();
```

Comment: thank you veyr much for your help. but i am unable to do the backgroundquery = false.

Comment: as i mentioned before yes. this helped me to solve the problem but if its still giving the same error for you try adding `pivot.RefreshTable();` after `pivot.PivotTableWizard(BackgroundQuery: false);`

Comment: if you are unable to define bgquery than try `pivot.PivotTableWizard( Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing,
                            false);`

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer seems to be that *sometimes* you have one row of data as the source for your pivot table and *sometimes* you don't - even when you think you still do. I have not been able to create a pivot table(or change the source of a pivot table) to one row of data:

[image: PivotTableErrorExplanation]

but if you are able to somehow figure out a way to do this then you have found your answer. There is no reason you can't have one row of data as your source just from a practical/theoretical perspective, but it looks like excel tries to prevent that from happening(maybe because the code assumes two rows). So if you do find a way, then it is probably a bug. Good Luck.

Comment: thank you., but sometimes it does work for one line of data and sometimes not

Comment: Well, like I said, then it is very likely a bug. Good luck getting someone from Microsoft coming on here and admitting to that.

Comment: i agree with you, but i dont think it would be of much use to me if they admitted anything to me :)

Comment: Yea, I agree. So we're in agreement. So if we are right then the best solution would be to make sure that your pivot table never tries to reference only one row of data. I'm not familiar with C# as of right now btw so I can't offer any advice about the best way to go about that. Good Luck.

Comment: i really do appreciate your effort and time and willingness to help with this

Comment: No problem. I'm here to learn and teach - sometimes(like in this case) I don't do much of either - but it's a general trend.