# convert .net 4.0 syntax OfType to .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I have this .NET 4.0 code:

```
var myTable = tables[1];
myTable = tables.Item["Table1"];
myTable = tables.OfType<Excel.ListObject>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Table1");
```

I am trying to compile with .NET 3.5 and getting a bunch of errors:

> Error 23  Property, indexer, or event 'Item' is not supported by the
>   language; try directly calling accessor method
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObjects.get_Item(object)'

and

> Error 24  'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObjects' does not contain
>   a definition for 'OfType' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.OfType(System.Linq.IQueryable)' has
>   some invalid arguments

and

> Error 25  Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObjects' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Can you please guide me on exactly what these errors mean so that I can try to convert this to .NET 3.5?

Thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: There's no simple fix for this.  The ListObjects interface is kinda fumbled, it has an Item property that's not the default property of the interface.  The default one is named _Default in the MSDN article.  C# version 3 and earlier only supports one indexer.  The wrong one for ListObjects.  You have to explicitly use get_Item(), just as the error message says.  Which breaks Linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question refers to an answer given for [This command requires at least two rows of source data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755248/this-command-requires-at-least-two-rows-of-source-data/12876478#comment17540673_12876478); the code is showing 3 different ways of accessing a table/listobject in code.

This was the code I posted:

```
    var myTable = tables[1];
    var myTable = tables.Item["Table1"];
    var myTable = tables.OfType<Excel.ListObject>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Table1");
```

I meant to illustrate that there are different ways of accessing a table in code.

To put it in context, I have created a Ribbon with a single button called "TestButton". Here is the entire code, should work with 3.5:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


    private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        var tables = worksheet.ListObjects;
        var table = tables.Item["Table1"]; // this is the line you are referring to

        //do something with table
    }
```